# why is printf prints just once in a loop, only for the first input?

Tags: c, printf

```
void hexToDec(){
    char numHex, numDec;
    int isNum, isLowAf, isHighAf;
    printf("Enter a reversed number in base 16:\n");
    scanf("%c", &numHex);
    while(numHex != '\n'){
        isNum = isHighAf = isLowAf = 0;
        if(numHex >= 48 && numHex <= 57)
            isNum = 1;
        if(numHex >= 65 && numHex <= 70)
            isHighAf = 1;
        if(numHex >= 97 && numHex <= 102)
            isLowAf = 1;
        if(!isNum && !isLowAf && !isHighAf)
             printf("Error! %c is not a valid digit in base 16\n", numHex);
        //else - Hexadecimal to Decimal converter
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &numHex);
    }
}
```

I can't use `string.h`  or arrays[] this task and I need to check every input I get and print every char that isn't digit in base 16. The problem is that it only check the first letter I enter and print not valid for it.

for example:

input:

```
lds
```

output:

```
Error! l is not a valid digit in base 16
```

expected:

```
Error! l is not a valid digit in base 16
Error! s is not a valid digit in base 16
```

Also I can't figure out why the while loop doesn't stop after I click Enter.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: You should use `'0'` instead of `48`, for example.

Comment: `numHex` will never be `\n`. The space at the beginning of the format string makes it skip over whitespace.

Comment: writing '0' or 48 is the same... and I tried scanning without space before %c and it didn't help.

Comment: Not the problem, but you should use `else if` since all the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: try : `numHex = getc(stdin)`; instead of `scanf("%c", &numHex);`

Also if you're using visual studio, `fflush` will not work for some reason. The alternative is `rewind(stdin)`

Comment: Get rid of the space before `%c` so you can read the newline. Otherwise you have an infinite loop. You should also check for EOF.

Comment: I'm not allow to use getc(stdin) funcntion

Comment: This is somewhat over complicated.  Why not:  `if( (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') { /* is hex */ } else { /* not hex */ }`.  Your test needlessly tests for a to f for example even after you have already determined that it is in the range 0 to 9, uses "magic" numbers rather than character constants, and created needless variables.

Comment: Your test needlessly tests for a to f for example even after you have already determined that it is in the range 0 to 9, uses "magic" numbers rather than character constants, and creates needless variables.  Since each character type is mutually exclusive you might use a single  enumerated type rather than three Booleans:  `enum ctype { NOTHEX, HEXNUMERIC, HEXLOWER, HEXUPPER } ;`.

Answer (score 2):

`fflush(stdin)` is not standard C. But on systems where it works (Windows), it will discard all the buffered input that hasn't yet been. So after scanning the first character `l`, this will cause `ds` to be discarded, and it will wait for you to type a new line of input.

Get rid of that call if you want it to process the remaining characters of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is not exiting because of the `space` in the second `scanf`.

Would be a tad nicer if character constants are used instead of hard coded numbers.

```
 while(numHex != '\n'){
    isNum = isHighAf = isLowAf = 0;
    if(numHex >= '0' && numHex <= '9')
        isNum = 1;
    else if(numHex >= 'A' && numHex <= 'F')
        isHighAf = 1;
    else if(numHex >= 'a' && numHex <= 'f')
        isLowAf = 1;
    if(!isNum && !isLowAf && !isHighAf)
         printf("Error! %c is not a valid digit in base 16\n", numHex);
    //else - Hexadecimal to Decimal converter
    //fflush(stdin);//undefined behavior
    scanf("%c", &numHex);
}
```

Comment: The space in the second `scanf()` was removed by edit 10 minutes before you posted.  The `fflush(stdin)` will cause all remaining buffered data to be discarded with Microsoft's implementation at least.   Your answer solves that issue to, but you did not mention it explicitly.

Comment: suggest also changing the second and third `if` to `else if` - once the character type is determined, there is no reason to test other types.

Comment: Agreed. have edited my post......thank you for the feedback!!!